# "Несмотря ни на что": запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Выделяется ли запятой оборот "несмотря ни на что" в подобных предложениях: "Несмотря ни на что(,) он все-таки достиг финиша"?

Answer (score 2):

**Несмотря ни на что**, он все-таки достиг финиша.

Как уже сказано, оборот обособляется в большинстве случаев и в любой позиции (в начале, конце, середине предложения), поэтому интересно рассмотреть такие случаи, когда оборот не обособляется. **Нет обособления при отсутствии паузы и тесном смысловом единстве с последующим словом**, например:

Его лиственная вершина скомкалась, холодные прутья рамы впились в нежные молодые листья, перерезали и изуродовали их, но дерево было упрямо, не жалело листьев, **несмотря ни на что давило на решётки,** и решётки уже подавались, хотя были сделаны из крепкого железа. [Вс. М. Гаршин. Attalea Princeps (1879)].

В данном случае оборот относится к одному из однородных членов и тесно связан с ним.

Answer (score 1):

Обстоятельственный оборот «несмотря ни на что» чаще выделяется знаками препинания (запятыми) ([Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_860&v=full))

Answer (score 1):

**несмотря́ ни на что**
Устойчивое сочетание (фразеологизм). Используется в качестве **наречия и вводного слова.**
**Значение:** при любых обстоятельствах, вопреки всему.
 *◆  — Евгений Павлыч, — сказал он с странною горячностью, схватив его за руку, — будьте уверены, что я вас считаю за самого благороднейшего и лучшего человека, несмотря ни на что; будьте в этом уверены…* Ф. М. Достоевский, «Идиот».
 *◆ Несмотря ни на что, она вечно будет жить и в памятниках прошлого, и в памятниках настоящего, и в памятниках будущего.* М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин, «Круглый год».

*Если бы,* если бы всё было ТАК просто, - вопрос не оставался бы без ответа почти пять лет и не просматривался бы так исключительно часто!

Заслуживающая внимания полемика по поводу "несмотря ни на что" есть [**здесь**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20&limitstart=0):

Вопрос № 279788
Нужна ли запятая в предложении: ***"Несмотря ни на что хотелось верить в мечту"?***
Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
**Запятая не требуется.**

Вопрос № 269882
Здравствуйте. Нужна ли запятая в предложении: ***"Можно ли оставаться человеком несмотря ни на что?"***
Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
**Запятая не нужна.**

Вопрос № 226538
Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая: ***они добивались должного успеха (,) несмотря ни на что.***
Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
**Запятую лучше не ставить.**

Я "проштудировала" всё, но, честное слово, *к однозначному выводу* так и не пришла... А что означает: "запятую лучше не ставить"? Получается, возможны два варианта!?

Теперь, собственно, о предложении, указанном в вопросе:
*достиг - как? - несмотря ни на что* (наречие) - возможно? Тогда запятая не нужна.